# json object is bahaving wrongly

Tags: php, json

I am test-running a web application
where in json is required. I have the following json
structure:

```
{
    "Articles": [
        {
            "Article": {
                "ID": 111,
                "title": "Idiot",
                "author": "Moron",
                "pubDate": "11/2/14", 
                "summary": "bla bla bla"
            },

            "Article": {
                "ID": 222,
                "title": "wisdom",
                "author": "wise one",
                "pubDate": "11/2/15", 
                "summary": "ha ha ha"
            }
        } 
    ]
}
```

I then decided to check if a matching ID exits before adding
any record. To this effect, I wrote a method, encased it within
a JSon class as follows:

```
public function ID_Exists($ID){

        $file = file_get_contents($this->FileName, true);
        $data = json_decode($file, false);       //get json in array string format 

        foreach($data as $child){
            foreach($child as $item){
                if($item->ID ==  $ID){
                    echo 'Exists';
                }else{
                    echo 'Non Existent';
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

I test-ran it like:

```
$Obj = new JSon('file.json');        //knows what to do
 if($Obj->ID_Exists(111)){
     //ok ! no problem
 }else{
     ////no problem
 }
```

Here's the output I got:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$ID in 
C:\Server\wamp\www\Oweb\libs\dmanager.php on line 635
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't want to use the array 
format of json_decode().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON structure is impossible. `Articles` is an array which contains a single object which contains the key `Article` twice - this cannot work.

Your structure needs to be:

```
{
    "Articles": [
        {
            "ID": 111,
            ...
        },
        {
            "ID": 222,
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Which you can traverse using:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach ($data->Articles as $article) {
    if ($article->ID == ..) ..
}
```

Comment: thanks deceze i'll do just as you said, nd i'll get back ASAP.

Comment: A million thanks to you deceze. it worked flawlessly. the reason i made such json structure is cos, i only wanted to mimic my xml structre that has <articles><article ID = ""><article></articles>. never realising that its impossible like that in json. You've just added to my knowledge repository. Thanks once more.